# SAS: Add asterix in Compute block (Traffic Lighting)

Tags: sas

I have a PROC REPORT output and want to add an asterick based on the value of the cell being less than 1.96. I don't want colours, just an asterick after the number. Can this be done with a format, or do I need an 'IF/ELSE' clause in the COMPUTE block?

```
data have1;
   input username $  betdate : datetime. stake winnings winner;
   dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
   format betdate DATETIME.;
   format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
   datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 90 -90 0
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 100 40 1
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 120 -120 0
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:00 50 15 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:05:00 30 5 1
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20 10 1
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 10 -10 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:40 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 -15 0
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:45 15 45 1
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 -35 0
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35 15 1
run;

PROC PRINT; RUN;

Proc rank data=have1 ties=mean out=ranksout1 groups=2;
     var    stake winner;
     ranks  stakeRank winnerRank;
run;

proc sql;
create table withCubedDeviations as
    select *,
    ((stake - (select avg(stake) from ranksout1 where stakeRank = main.stakeRank and  winnerRank = main.winnerRank))/(select std(stake) from ranksout1 where stakeRank = main.stakeRank and  winnerRank = main.winnerRank)) **3 format=8.2 as cubeddeviations
    from ranksout1 main;    
quit;

PROC REPORT DATA=withCubedDeviations NOWINDOWS out=report;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, ( N stake=avg cubeddeviations skewness);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP  ORDER=INTERNAL '';
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS  ORDER=INTERNAL '';
    DEFINE cubeddeviations / analysis 'SumCD' noprint;
    DEFINE N / 'Bettors';
    DEFINE avg / analysis mean 'Avg' format=8.2;
    DEFINE skewness / computed format=8.2 'Skewness';
    COMPUTE skewness;
        _C5_ =  _C4_ * (_C2_ / ((_C2_ -1) * (_C2_ - 2)));
        _C9_ =  _C8_ * (_C6_ / ((_C6_ -1) * (_C6_ - 2)));
    ENDCOMP;
RUN;
```

This is just an example, so this won't make statistical sense, but if the value for SKEWNESS is greater than 1 I need to put a single asterick, two asterix if it's greater than 5 and three asterix if the value is greater than ten. Also, if the asterix could be in superscript that would be even better.

I've been testing the following, but to no avail:

```
PROC FORMAT; 
    picture onestar . = " " low - high = "9.9999^{super *}";*^{super***};
    picture twostar . = " " low - high = "9.9999^{super **}";*^{super***};
    picture threestar . = " " low - high = "9.9999^{super ***}";*^{super***};
run;

PROC REPORT DATA=withCubedDeviations NOWINDOWS out=report;
    COLUMN stakerank winnerrank, ( N stake=avg cubeddeviations);
    DEFINE stakerank / GROUP  ORDER=INTERNAL '';
    DEFINE winnerrank / ACROSS  ORDER=INTERNAL '';
    DEFINE cubeddeviations / analysis 'SumCD' noprint;
    DEFINE N / 'Bettors';
    DEFINE avg / mean 'Avg' format=8.2;
    compute avg;
        if _C3_ > 1.96 then call define('_C3_','format','onestar.');
    endcomp;
RUN;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you need:

```
proc format;
picture skewaskf
-1 <-<0 = '00009.99' (mult=100 prefix='-')
0-<1 = '00009.99' (mult=100) 
1-<5 = '00009.99*'(mult=100)
5-<10= '00009.99**'(mult=100)
10-high='00009.99***'(mult=100);
quit;
```

Extend for the negatives further.

Comment: Great. I'm doing this for a t-test that I'm calculating in a column in the PROC REPORT, so I need to apply this format the p-value for that t-test. Is there a formula is SAS to return a p-value for the t-distribution that takes a t-stat and degrees of freedom as parameters? I need to output a p-value for each group so don't want to just run PROC UNIVARIATE.

Comment: Probably, not a statistician but there are lots of functions like that - `tinv` for example.